# Prove that $R$ has no zero divisors and $R$ has an identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with more than one element such that for each nonzero $a \in R$ there is a unique $b \in R$ such that  $aba=a$. Prove that $R$ has no zero divisors and $R$ has an identity.

Comment: Assume he had tried zero divisors, i e, there $a$ and $c$ such that $ac=0$ but I could not finish it, and for identity,  tried to manipulate the expression, but have come to no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Servaes's answer has shown the non-existence of zero divisors. Now let $a \not =0, a \in R$, so $\exists b \in R$ with $aba=a$. Let $ab=t, ba=u$, where $t, u \in R$. Now $ta=a$ so $xta=xa \, \forall x \in R$ so $(xt-x)a=0$ so ($a \not =0$) $xt=x \, \forall x\in R$. Similarly $ux=x \, \forall x \in R$. Finally $u=ut=t$ so $u=t$ is the (multiplicative) identity.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a\in R$ be nonzero and let $c\in R$ be such that $ac=0$. There exists a *unique* element $b\in R$ such that $aba=a$, so from the identities
$$a(b+c)a=(ab+ac)a=(ab)a=aba=a,$$
it follows that $b+c=b$, and hence that $c=0$. This shows that $a$ is not a zero divisor

Comment: I think the second part is not correct, since the OP has asked you to prove that R has identity not to assume it, am I right?

Comment: You are right, I was mislead by the other answer. I'll give it some more thought.